# XMLHTTPRequest.response is null when trying to read an excel file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

Hi new to alot of this i'm trying to use the below typescript to grab an excel file before converting it to json to use as a data source for charts i'm using. it's bugging out in the onload function because i think the .response = null -  readystate = 1 (OPENED) and the status = 0 (Open or Unsent). not too sure wjy it's null.. I've read the readstate needs to be = 4 and status = 200 (finishing opening it) before it can work. but i don't know how i can do that?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { read, IWorkBook, IWorkSheet, utils } from 'ts-xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class OperationDataService {
    oUrl: string;
    xhr: any;
    wb: IWorkBook;
    wbSheet: IWorkSheet;
    arraybuffer: any;
    data: any;
    arr: any;
    bstr: any;

    getData() {
        this.oUrl = './assets/operations.xlsx';
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xhr.open('GET', this.oUrl, true);
        this.xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        console.log('Service Constructor ' + this.xhr.open + ' - ' + this.xhr.readyState + ' - ' + this.xhr.response + ' - ' + this.xhr.status);

        if (this.xhr.readyState === 4) {

            if (this.xhr.status === 200) {

                this.xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    console.log('in side function');

                    this.arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;

                    console.log('ArrayBuffer ' + this.arraybuffer);

                    /* convert data to binary string */
                    this.data = new Uint8Array(this.arraybuffer);
                    this.arr = new Array();

                    for (let item of this.data) {
                        this.arr[item] = String.fromCharCode(this.data[item]);
                    }

                    this.bstr = this.arr.join('');
                    console.log(this.xhr.responseText);

                    this.wb = read(this.bstr, { type: 'binary' });
                    this.wbSheet = this.wb.Sheets[0];

                    this.objAr = utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 });
                    console.log(utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 }));
                    console.log('get data set');

                    return this.objAr;
                };
            }
        }

        this.xhr.send();
    }

}
```

---

UPDATE

Thanks the below has got me up to the javescript lib to convert the excel to json - seems to be a issue with a JSzip version in the dependencies of ts-xlsx but the XMLHtpRequest GET has worked i can display the binary data in the browser.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { read, IWorkBook, IWorkSheet, utils } from 'ts-xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class OperationDataService {
    oUrl: string;
    xhr: any;
    wb: IWorkBook;
    wbSheet: IWorkSheet;
    arraybuffer: any;
    data: any;
    arr: any;
    bstr: any;

    getData() {
        this.oUrl = './assets/operations.xlsx';
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xhr.open('GET', this.oUrl, true);
        this.xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        this.xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {

                    this.arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;

                    // /* convert data to binary string */
                    this.data = new Uint8Array(this.arraybuffer);
                    this.arr = new Array();

                    for (let i = 0; i !== this.data.length; ++i) {
                    this.arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(this.data[i]);
                    }
                    this.bstr = this.arr.join('');

                    this.wb = read(this.bstr, { type: 'binary' });

                    this.wbSheet = this.wb.Sheets[0];
                    this.objAr = utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 });

                    return this.objAr;

            }.bind(this));

            this.xhr.send(null);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a file using `XMLHttpRequest` [can be simpler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) than that:

```
this.oUrl = './assets/operations.xlsx';
this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
this.xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var arraybuffer = this.response;
    ...
});
this.xhr.open('GET', this.oUrl, true);
this.xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

You can do it your way as well, but then it should be like:

```
this.xhr.onreadystatechange =() => {
    if (this.xhr.readyState === 4 && this.xhr.status === 200) {
        this.arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;

    }
}
```

If you are using the `onload` event then you don't need to check the `readyState`.
In any case you never really added the event listener because you adding it only if `readyState === 4` and `status === 200` which will never happen before you actually sent the request.

As for the response, it looks like that because `xlsx` files are zipped.

---

#### Edit

If you're assigning an event listener function as an anonymous one then the `this` in the body of that function won't be your object but the `XMLHttpRequest` object so it should be:

```
this.xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var arraybuffer = this.response;
    ...
});
```

Unless you bind it:

```
this.xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;
    ...
}.bind(this));
```

If you're using an arrow function then `this` will be your object:

```
this.xhr.addEventListener("load",() => {
    var arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks i tried to use the first code sample - just to see if it works and i get the same error in the browser -  `Cannot read property 'response' of undefined.`

Comment: `getData() {
        this.oUrl = './assets/operations.xlsx';
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
            this.arraybuffer = this.xhr.response;
        });
        this.xhr.open('GET', this.oUrl, true);
        this.xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        this.xhr.send();
    } `

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about an error in your question. In any case check my revised answer.